# Comment selector on ending tag of CSS/SCSS in Sublime 3

Tags: css, sass, sublimetext3

I've been around this for ages, I already have a proper HTML solution for this (thanks for the new `comment` and `comment_template` settings). But now I need the same for my SCSS and CSS.

So I don't lose "who's closing who" my code normally looks like this:

```sass
.myclass{
  p{
    margin-bottom:10px;
  } // p
  a{
    color:blue;
    &:hover{
      color:tomato;
    } // &:hover
    &.active{
      color:potato;
    } // &.active
  } // a
  .myclasscontent{
    padding:5px;
  } // .myclasscontent
} // .myclass
```

That helps me in a number of ways, but mostly checking for unclosed tags and knowing who this chunk of code is inside of. When I collapse the lines I also know what block of content is closing properly (for the selector starts and ends like this:

```sass
.myclass{
  ...
} // .myclass
```

CSS version

```css
.myclass{
  ...
} /* .myclass */
```

I just want that, when automatically closing the brackets { it already puts the selector along with the closing brackets.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't now whether this input is usefull but I would recommend looking for a plugin like this: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/RainbowBrackets. This doesn't bloat your code with rather unusefull comments and it has the same purpose as your comments.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but it isn't enough. It doesn't bloat the code because it get removed on compilation, and I want to be able to understand the code in any IDE (our devs use another one).

Comment: So to summarize, when you close the css class/id with a ending `}`, you want the class name at the same line as that of the ending `}`, commented out ?

Comment: That's right, thanks for the simplification